# Get the value for key in json array in php

Tags: php, json

How to get the corresponding value for key associated

```
[{"name":"challenge","properties":[{"name":"mobileNo","value":"aa"},{"name":"challengeT","value":"1Day"},{"name":"emailId","value":"ff@gmail.com"},{"name":"deviceId","value":"9500e297-081b-4f97-93b7-dafddc55db31"}]},{"name":"challenge","properties":[{"name":"emailId","value":"a@b.com"},{"name":"mobileNo","value":"345345"},{"name":"deviceId","value":"435435dfgdfg"}]}]
```

Comment: 1. your json is not valid; 2. `json_decode` your data once you have validated it, then issue a `var_dump` to check corresponding PHP structure.

Comment: `How to get the corresponding value for key associated`? what kind of a question is that? what is the end result that you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

Your Json is valid. You can validate at following
 website: http://jsonlint.com/

You have to use a php "json_decode()" function to decode a json encoded data.
Basically json_decode() function converts JSON data to a PHP array.

**Syntax: json_decode( data, dataTypeBoolean, depth, options )**

**data** : -  The json data that you want to decode in PHP.

**dataTypeBoolean(Optional)** :-  boolean that makes the function return a PHP Associative Array if set to "true", or return a PHP stdClass object if you omit this parameter or set it to "false". Both data types can be accessed like an array and use array based PHP loops for parsing.

**depth** :- Optional recursion limit. Use an integer as the value for this parameter.

**options** :- Optional JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING parameter.

***Now Comes to your Code***

```
$json_string = '[{"name":"challenge","properties":[{"name":"mobileNo","value":"aa"},{"name":"challengeT","value":"1Day"},{"name":"emailId","value":"ff@gmail.com"},{"name":"deviceId","value":"9500e297-081b-4f97-93b7-dafddc55db31"}]},{"name":"challenge","properties":[{"name":"emailId","value":"a@b.com"},{"name":"mobileNo","value":"345345"},{"name":"deviceId","value":"435435dfgdfg"}]}]' ;
```

**Assign a valid json data to a variable $json_string within single quot's ('') as
   json string already have double quots.**

```
// here i am decoding a json string by using a php 'json_decode' function, as mentioned above & passing a true parameter to get a PHP associative array otherwise it will bydefault return a PHP std class objecy array.

$json_decoded_data = json_decode($json_string, true);

// just can check here your encoded array data.
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($json_decoded_data);

// loop to extract data from an array
foreach ($json_decoded_data as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key <br/>";
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        echo "$key2 = $value2 <br />";
    }
}

Output : 
0 
name = challenge 
properties = Array 
1 
name = challenge 
properties = Array
```